# F#: shortest way to convert a string option to a string

Tags: f#, tostring

The objective is to convert a `string option` that comes out of some nicely typed computation to a plain `string` that can then be passed to the UI/`printf`/URL/other things that just want a string and know nothing of option types. `None` should just become the empty string.

The obvious way is to do a `match` or an `if` on the input:

`input |> fun s -> fun s -> match s with | Some v -> v | _ -> ""` or

`input |> fun s -> if s.IsSome then s.Value else ""`

but while still being one-liners, these still take up quite a lot of line space. I was hoping to find the shortest possible method for doing this.

Comment: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6672880-add-a-option-getordefault-and-other-new-functions

Comment: The RFC mentioned in the comments on your link is now an argument about names https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/issues/60 -- a good sign it'll not get resolved ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use the function `defaultArg input ""` which in your code that uses forward pipe would be:

```
input |> fun s -> defaultArg s ""
```

Here's another way of writing the same but without the lambda:

```
input |> defaultArg <| ""
```

It would be better if we had a version in the F# core with the arguments flipped. Still I think this is the shortest way without relaying in other libraries or user defined functions.

**UPDATE**

Now in F# 4.1 FSharp.Core provides `Option.defaultValue` which is the same but with arguments flipped, so now you can simply write:

```
Option.defaultValue "" input
```

Which is pipe-forward friendly:

```
input |> Option.defaultValue ""
```

Comment: `defaultArg input ""`?

Comment: @PetSerAl -- yes, but `input` comes out of another computation on that same line, hence the all the piping.

Comment: @PetSerAl I thought that was the obvious way to use the function that's why I omitted it, but will add it for completeness.

Comment: I would discourage using `defaultArg` in that fashion - it has an established meaning of providing a default value for an optional argument, and using it outside of that context is inviting confusion.

Comment: @scrwtp Yes, I agree, mainly because of the name which is a bit unfortunate, it could have a more generic name. Still I think it's the "shortest way", which is in the title of the question.

Comment: Indeed. Something `getValueDefaultingTo` would have been better, but would have also probably caused a war. This shaves two characters off my `fold`-based effort, so -- excellent work!

Answer (score 5):

The obvious way is to write yourself a function to do it, and if you put it in an `Option` module, you won't even notice it's not part of the core library:

```
module Option =
    let defaultTo defValue opt = 
        match opt with
        | Some x -> x
        | None -> defValue
```

Then use it like this:

```
input |> Option.defaultTo ""
```

Comment: Is this not exactly the same as `defaultArg`, just with a slightly better name? Why not define it as `let defaultTo = defaultArg`?

Comment: Not exactly, it has the arguments flipped which as I said before would make more sense for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The NuGet package FSharpX.Extras has [`Option.getOrElse`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/573c817ac56edb240b20f9bd35044d71beafc0d5/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L212) which can be composed nicely.

`let x = stringOption |> Option.getOrElse ""`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found so far is `input |> Option.fold (+) ""`.

...which is just a shortened version of `input |> Option.fold (fun s t -> s + t) ""`.

I suspect that it's the shortest I'll get, but I'd like to hear if there are other short ways of doing this that would be easier to understand by non-functional programmers.

Comment: This is super cryptic. Somebody reading your code (including yourself in the future) won't have any idea what's going on.

Comment: it's not only cryptic, it's also only accidentally correct due to empty string being the additive identity of string concatenation. If you want to use `fold`, make it `Option.fold (fun _ x -> x)`

Comment: I wouldn't say it was an accident -- it was really quite deliberate! On the subject of what other people would or would not find cryptic now or in the future, I'd rather not go there -- this is not very cryptic to _me_ now, nor, do I suspect, will it grow to be so later. Different people find different things readable.