# Option to value with default value

Tags: f#, option-type

With the help of answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436406/f-shortest-way-to-convert-a-string-option-to-a-string) I need help with the specific syntax on how to retrieve values from option types in the following case.

```
type Query = {
    q : string
    pageSize : int option
}

let search (query : Query) =
    let url = sprintf "foo.com?q=%spageSize=%i" query.q (query.pageSize |> 10 |< query.pageSize) // ???
```

Syntax help for `(query.pageSize |> 10 |< query.pageSize)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Option.defaultValue` is your friend:

```
type Query = {
  q : string
  pageSize : int option
}
let q = {q = "foo"; pageSize = None}
let p = q.pageSize |> Option.defaultValue 10
```

Comment: Available from F# 4.1.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you linked provides a pretty clear illustration of the syntax:

```
input |> defaultArg <| ""
```

In your case, the input is `query.pageSize` and the default value is `10` instead of empty string. So:

```
query.pageSize |> defaultArg <| 10
```

Comment: what is defaultArg? that's not clear, also see my edit please

Comment: `defaultArg` is a built-in function, defined in `FSharp.Core`. The error in your edit refers to some different line, not the one you posted.